# Rails - Postgresql updating datetime leaves me with correct date but time is 00:00:00

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, rails-postgresql

I've been trying to update a datetime field with the current date & time.

```
current_user.update_attributes!(:watched_post_its_at => Time.now)
```

But it leaves me with `2013-10-31 00:00:00`

If I go into console and write it like

```
User.find(8).update_attributes!(:watched_post_its_at => Time.now)
```

It leaves me with the correct time: `2013-10-31 10:57:56`

What am I missing here?

On Rails 4 with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck on the same issue. I found that I need to bring the format explicitly for Postgres. In my situation, I use this:

```
Time.at(time_param).to_formatted_s(:db)
```

In you problem you need to use .to_formatted_s(:db), like this

```
User.find(8).update_attributes!(:watched_post_its_at => Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db))
```

I checked in my code and it works
[image]